# What should we do with [kubeadm] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, clean-up

[kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/) is a tool to *create* Kubernetes clusters. This activity is almost always off-topic for Stack Overflow, at least when done with a *command line tool* - as `kubeadm` is.

The tag [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm) is driving questions that are **off-topic** and should be asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm) instead.

What should we do with the tag and the questions?

Comment: I'm not sure how the mere existence of a tag can drive questions.

Comment: I pretty frequently VTC questions on installing Kubernetes clusters, and I've at least considered editing the tag wiki to say "this isn't on-topic here".  How important is the "professional" part of the Server Fault description (would questions about Raspberry Pi clusters be welcomed there)?  DevOps.SE is the other likely place to point at (though a little less for "installing a cluster" type questions probably).

Comment: True, SuperUser is probably better for installing Kubernetes on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Paulie_D because people follow signals to figure out what they can ask. Having a tag, is a strong one.

Comment: You've edited the tag description to mention that questions are likely to be off topic and should be asked on SF, what more would you like to see happen?

Comment: Related [People don't read the tag excerpts because we don't swat them into their faces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575)

Comment: @Paulie_D [An example of tag signaling acceptance of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944943/custom-cdr-fields-for-outgoing-calls-using-asterisk?noredirect=1#comment36884366_23944943)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having a look at the last 10 questions for [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm), none of them seem to be *on-topic* on Stack Overflow. And I think most of the 564 questions with this tag is **off-topic**. I suggest that this tag should be *burninated* - since it is *off-topic*.

Here is a list of the 10 latest questions for [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm) and what probably should be done with them.

- [Kubernetes DNS resolution issues with CoreDNS and Ubuntu 18.04 cluster deployed with Kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485640/kubernetes-dns-resolution-issues-with-coredns-and-ubuntu-18-04-cluster-deployed) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Change exposed version of a worker machine on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474885/change-exposed-version-of-a-worker-machine-on-kubernetes) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Changing kube-controller-manager.yaml with minkube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67465340/changing-kube-controller-manager-yaml-with-minkube) - appearently related to Minikube and not kubeadm.
- [Kubernetes: how to write cluster token to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389606/kubernetes-how-to-write-cluster-token-to-a-file) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Kubeadm - unable to join nodes - request canceled while waiting for connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67383423/kubeadm-unable-to-join-nodes-request-canceled-while-waiting-for-connection) - belongs to Server Fault
- [Kubelet message “cni config uninitialized” when installing k8s 1.21.0 on Raspberry Pi4 w/ Alpine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351791/kubelet-message-cni-config-uninitialized-when-installing-k8s-1-21-0-on-raspber) - probably belongs to Super User
- [Restore HA kubeadm cluster with internal etcd running as pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301902/restore-ha-kubeadm-cluster-with-internal-etcd-running-as-pod) - belongs to Server Fault
- [kubeadm init error: kubeadm timed out waiting for the condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256430/kubeadm-init-error-kubeadm-timed-out-waiting-for-the-condition) - belongs to Server Fault
- [Problem pulling image from private repo using Kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222431/problem-pulling-image-from-private-repo-using-kubeadm) - belongs to Server Fault
- [Kubernetes slaves are showing offline in the Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036081/kubernetes-slaves-are-showing-offline-in-the-jenkins) - this does not seem to be related to `kubeadm`.

Comment: That last one seems off topic even if it's not about kubeadm