# Burninate [kubeadm] tag - it's off-topic

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) is a *command line tool* for installing Kubernetes clusters. These questions are almost always off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Let's review the last 12 questions with tag [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm):

- [Choosing Public IP or VPC IP for creating Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120540/choosing-public-ip-or-vpc-ip-for-creating-kubernetes-cluster) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [kubernetes master node installation details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120503/kubernetes-master-node-installation-details) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [K8s worker nodes stuck to high CPU consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118979/k8s-worker-nodes-stuck-to-high-cpu-consumption) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Kubelet - Factory “crio” was unable to handle container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101198/kubelet-factory-crio-was-unable-to-handle-container) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Install Kerberos Kdc on a Kubernetes Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989862/install-kerberos-kdc-on-a-kubernetes-cluster) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Add new control plane node got failed k8s 1.21.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67969237/add-new-control-plane-node-got-failed-k8s-1-21-0) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Kubeadm join not working after installing Flannel [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967781/kubeadm-join-not-working-after-installing-flannel) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Can you create a multi-arch k8s cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929975/can-you-create-a-multi-arch-k8s-cluster) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Kubernetes cluster reconfiguring after the changing of hostnames and IP subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927852/kubernetes-cluster-reconfiguring-after-the-changing-of-hostnames-and-ip-subnet) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Re-installed node cannot join Kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921552/re-installed-node-cannot-join-kubernetes-cluster) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Kubernetes bare metal cluster - problems resetting. Some nodes not drained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856659/kubernetes-bare-metal-cluster-problems-resetting-some-nodes-not-drained) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [invalid configuration for GroupVersionKind /v1, Kind=ConfigMap: kind and apiVersion is mandatory information that must be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810310/invalid-configuration-for-groupversionkind-v1-kind-configmap-kind-and-apivers) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [restarting master node - vanished from the unit file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809438/restarting-master-node-vanished-from-the-unit-file) - belongs to Server Fault.
- [Kubeadm ClusterConfig specify feature gate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676117/kubeadm-clusterconfig-specify-feature-gate) - belongs to Server Fault.

As we see, these 12 last questions were **exclusively off-topic**. This is a follow-up question from [What should we do with [kubeadm] questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407681/what-should-we-do-with-kubeadm-questions) where I also was reviewing the last 10 questions at the time, and it also happened that they were **exclusively off-topic**.

Can we burninate this tag since it is off-topic?

Comment: Nothing really to be said, here ... just upvote and get the deed done. (But I said it, anyway?)

Comment: How about [`kubectl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubectl?tab=Newest)? It's not much different, but the GCP flavor.

Comment: @zeitler kubeadm is very different than kubectl . kubectl controls clusters. kubeadm installs clusters. kubeadm is solely within the range of admins; kubectl is a tool used by many personas. It has nothing to do with which K8S distribution you are using.

Comment: @DavidOgren I still don't see how that pertains programming tasks. A glance to the latest asked questions, I don't see many questions about doing programatic tasks. Just admin/user tasks, like which user submitted a job (admin), creating users (admin), stopping/terminating and deleting services (user, admin), and none of them are trying to be programmatic about it.

Comment: I don't really have a strong opinion on whether kubectl pertains to programming tasks; I think it could be argued either way. But the statement that kubectl is just the GCP flavor of kubeadm is just untrue: they are very different and that difference was my only point.