# Burninate [kubectl] tag - it's off-topic

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I saw a question today to burninate the [kubeadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubeadm) tag.

[Burninate [kubeadm] tag - it's off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408699/burninate-kubeadm-tag-its-off-topic)

and then it hit me that [kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubectl) also has a similar condition.

Let's see the last few questions tagged [kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubectl):

[kubeadm join failure: couldn't validate the identity of the API server [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135198/kubeadm-join-failure-couldnt-validate-the-identity-of-the-api-server)

[How to debug OOMKilled in Prometheus Pod? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123514/how-to-debug-oomkilled-in-prometheus-pod)

**and many more, many of them being closed.**

@[Martin Zeitler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/549372/martin-zeitler) also mentioned the same thing in the comments of the previous question.

Can we Burninate this tag as well since It's off-topic?

Comment: And then what? Someone's going to create it again. Mods can't blacklist tags anymore.

Comment: I don't get why people are downvoting this. If you look at the 10 newest questions, they are also off topic.

Comment: @Braiam Oh well, It's fine. I just wanted to let people know about this. No problem If they downvote it. It's not like I am gonna lose or gain any rep from meta questions.

Comment: @oguzismail Well... sorry, I did not know that mods cannot blacklist tags anymore.

Comment: @oguzismail I don't get why you believe that just because someone is going to create it, we should just give up.

Comment: Worth noting that at over 2,400 questions, this would be an intensive burn process.