# Synonymize [project-calico] and [calico]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[project-calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-calico) and [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) both refer to the same tool, which is some kind of networking thingy for Kubernetes. "Calico" and "Project Calico" both seem to be legit names, since the homepage at https://www.projectcalico.org/ uses both, so both tag names are reasonable ways to refer to the tool. Questions are split pretty evenly across the two tags.

I don't have the power to synonymize them since I have zero score in both tags. Perhaps a mod could do so?

I would suggest [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) as the main tag and [project-calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-calico) as the synonym, since a search for uses in posts (see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=calico and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22project+calico%22) reveals that people almost always refer to Calico just as "Calico", not as "Project Calico".

A little bit of extra history about this tag, for the record:

- there was previously some ambiguity about whether [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) referred to Project Calico (the Kubernetes thing) or The Calico Project, an entirely unrelated framework for learning about programming that people often seemed to use for playing with electronics from Python. The tag wiki indicated the latter up until last week, but well over 90% of the questions tagged [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) were about Kubernetes.
- The Calico Project has been abandoned for years now and its website, calicoproject.org, is now dead. Only 10 questions were ever posted in the [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) tag about it. The last of those was in October 2016, so I don't foresee us ever getting any more Calico Project questions in future. Since October 2016, all [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) questions have been Kubernetes questions.
- Last week, user Hod submitted [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29252434) updating the [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) tag wiki to be about the Kubernetes project, to match the dominant usage of it. I approved that and then retagged all the old Calico Project questions with a new tag, [calico-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico-project). Thus the old ambiguity about which project the tag referred to is now eliminated. Unless anybody objects to any of those actions and wants to revert them, I think that means the [project-calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-calico) and [calico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calico) tags now unambiguously refer to the same thing as each other, and ready to synonymize.

I don't have any expertise in either Project Calico or The Calico Project - I've never used either - but in this case it seems straightforward to see that this is the right thing to do even without such knowledge.

Comment: I usually see Calico referenced as a Kubernetes networking layer, and almost every Calico-related question is about cluster or network administration and not programming.  Rather than a synonym request, following the lines of [What should we do with \[kubeadm\] questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407681/what-should-we-do-with-kubeadm-questions) and discouraging those questions on SO might be more appropriate.